# Did C.S Peirce ever express anything in the same vein to meaning holism?

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-science, metaphysics

C.S Peirce's philosophy is considered a predecessor to the logical positivism.
In some respects Peirce is also thought as having prefigured several major philosophical ideas that came after logical positivism.
Did C.S Peirce ever express anything in the same vein to meaning holism?

Comment: This is controversial. Quine did not think that Peirce's semantics is committed to holism. He did credit him for anticipating positivist verificationism, and thought that when combined with confirmation holism it implies semantic holism, but did not think that Peirce expressed confirmation holism. Almeder argues otherwise in [Peirce on Meaning](https://www.jstor.org/stable/20115369) citing a number of passages on p.15.

Comment: @Conifold I get the feeling that Almeder is trying to interpret Peirce's (commonplace?)statements as implying confirmation holism. Do you know if theories were defined by someone before Peirce as a set of statements or propositions?

Comment: @Conifold Can you help me find the original document where Peirce writes that one can make any proposition in a theory true by changing other sentences in the theory ?

Comment: You mean MS 290 that Almeder cites? I am not sure it has been published. [Commens](http://www.commens.org/bibliography/manuscript/peirce-charles-s-1905-issues-pragmaticism-ms-r-290) only gives a summary and mentions that only a small part was published. Almeder writes "*Reference to the
unpublished papers are preceded by an MS... The microfilm edition of the unpublished papers can be obtained from the Widener Library, Harvard University, Cambridge, Mass.*" [Harvard library](https://library.harvard.edu/collections/charles-s-peirce-papers) says that digitization of late papers is ongoing.